# PHPDOC @property associating to a getter

Tags: yii, phpstorm, phpdoc

I'm using YII and have liberally set `@property` phpdoc statements to all my models.

In my IDE (phpstorm), I can Control + Click methods and fields to be taken to their implementations, but when I do so for magic methods, it takes me to the top of the class definition, which is incorrect.

How can I set it up so that it takes me to the associated getter method?

Comment: Umm, you're saying you have explicitly defined get methods but the properties themselves are undefined magic?  I'll need an example here to be sure I'm understanding the layout correctly :-)

Comment: It's Yii's magic, so it isn't concern phpdoc. When you using some property, Yii looks it in current object, if it's not found, Yii looks for `'get'.$propertyName` method, if it exists Yii calls it.

Comment: Specifically, Yii uses getters and setters to allow dynamic code to be executed when accessing properties. But it doesn't appear that phpdoc has a mechanism for specifying a method that is implementing a property.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand it that

`@property` and `@method`  methods tags  are only allowed in the class-level docblock.Both of these tags gives hint to developer about availability about methods/properties implemented through megic methods `__call($method,$params)`, `__get($var)` and `__set($var,$val)`.

In yii you don't need to define getter/setter methods explicitly for class attributes. So an attributes is access through  [`'get'.$attributeName` e.g](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/base/CComponent.php#L107)

```
 /**
 * Class User
 *
 * @method string getFirstName()
 * @method void setFirstName(string $firstName)
 *
 */
class User extends CModel{
    var $firstName;
}

$u= new User();
$username=$u->getFirstName();
$u->setFirstName('Testuser');
```

In the context of Yii , the above code is true bcz of magic method  `'get'.$attributeName`  for call attributes.

Since `@property` and `@method`  are class level @tags your only bet is to add them to class and Ctrl+click will send focus to respective class `docblock`